# wildcard in prisma full text search with postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, full-text-search, prisma

So I want to implement search feature to my web. In mysql we have `*` wildcard for 0 or more character match. But it seems we don't have any for postgress sql, I already checked the prisma documentation but I found nothing. I also tried `&>` and `&<` but it doesnt work.
Here's my code.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    var searchWords = req.query.search.split(" ")
    searchWords = searchWords.map(word => {
    // return `wildcard${word}wildcard`
        return `${word}`
    })

    const query = searchWords.join(" | ")
    console.log(query)
    const data = await prisma.diary.findMany(
        {
            where: {

                body: {
                    search: query
                }, title: {
                    search: query
                }
            },
            orderBy: {
                timecreated: 'desc'
            },
            take: 10
        }
    )

    data.map(x => {
        x.timecreated = x.timecreated.toString()
        x.lastedited = x.lastedited.toString()
        return x
    })

    await prisma.$disconnect()
    res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Tanonic I decided to use regular search with "LIKE" clause, as far I know there is no wildcard for full text search with postgress sql.

Answer (score 4):

Use suffix `:*`:

```
{ search: `${word}:*` }
```